# Intersecting two text files by its location

Tags: awk

I have two text files and I need to intersect by location

File1

```
cat02 2 5
```

File2

```
cat02 1 xxx xxx
cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat02 4 aqw ede efd
cat02 5 aws ede as
cat02 6 aqw
cat03 1 aaa
cat03 2 wer
```

expected output

```
cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat02 4 aqw ede efd
cat02 5 aws ede as
```

I tried with join by sorting both files but could not able to fetch the location

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Does File1 always contain only one line and is it intended that the upper and lower case is different (Cat02 vs cat02)?

Comment: @Cyrus Sorry just typing error I have made my changes, Yeah both are in lower case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested  with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  start[$1]=$2
  till[$1]=$3
  next
}
$2>=start[$1] && $2<=till[$1]
' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                          ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file1 is being read.
  start[$1]=$2                    ##Creating start with index $1 and value is $2.
  till[$1]=$3                     ##Creating til with index $1 and value is $3 here.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
$2>=start[$1] && $2<=till[$1]     ##Checking condition if start with 1st field index value is greater than 2nd field and lesser than till value then print line.
' Input_file1  Input_file2        ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: If I have more than one locations on file 1 (one per line) How do I change this code for finding all the location @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @user90, IMHO I would like to request you to open a new question for this one because future users referring this thread will be confused otherwise kindly do open a new question for same thank you.